# What does "Something" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter, order-of-the-phoenix

Context: End of the Order of The Pheonix:

> Harry Potter: I've been thinking about something Dumbledore said to
> me.
>
> Ron: What's that?
>
> Harry Potter: That even though we've got a fight ahead of us...we've
> got one thing that Voldemort doesn't have. **Something** worth fighting
> for.

What does "Something" refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's anything specific, more the general idea, fairly common in fiction, that the good guys will win because they're fighting for a cause, for family, for justice, things like that, while villains stereotypically do the things they do simply because they're evil. In actuality, of course, most villains have things they're fighting for, things they care dearly about, but I suppose that then you get into the semantics of "Well, we're fighting for something real, the American Way... Professor Xytonium just wants money and control over the world supply of transistors."

More generally, this may be referring to Harry having "the power that he [Voldemort] knows not", in the narrative, love.

Answer (score 1):

Love. They have love to fight for.

Or, less saccharine sweet, they have each other; family and friends.

Voldemort does not know or understand love, and he certainly has no friends.